# how to enable memcached in wamp in windows?

Tags: php, memcached, wamp

Iam running WAMP server and just enabled php_memcache extension and have tried the code

```
<?php
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

    $version = $memcache->getVersion();
    echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

    $tmp_object = new stdClass;
    $tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
    $tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

    $memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
    echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

    $get_result = $memcache->get('key');
    echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";

    var_dump($get_result);
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: `memcache` or `memcached`? PHP supports both, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: What was the response you got ?

Comment: I got  Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in D:\wamp\www\maheshsir\mc.php on line 2

Comment: Have you installed the `memcached` server as well?? `http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php`. Memcache ie.e php_memcache is just an interface to a `memcached server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to connect MySql server without installing it. First you have to install a memcached server. You can use [couchbase server with memcache bucket](http://www.couchbase.com/memcached) on Windows. IMHO it's the best port for Windows OS.